# Open a URL in opera mini browser

Tags: android

I've been trying to find out how to create an intent that will open the specified URL in opera mini browser and i have opera mini browser installed on my android device.

Answer (score 7):

`startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(...)));`

where `...` is the URL you wish to navigate to.

If Opera Mini is your default browser, or if you do not have a default browser, this can open in Opera Mini.

If you want to force the user to choose a browser, rather than use a default, use:

`startActivity(createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(...)), 'Pick a Browser'));`